# How to output three arrays out of two arrays with a given condition

Tags: php, arrays

I know you don't have much time with little problems but I'm quite lost with this question. Can someone please help me. Its a school's assignment which is giving me all these troubles. Here goes the question.

Suppose you have 2 arrays, each array contain objects with id and data fields.
You need to write function that will return 3 new arrays with the rules:

1) 1st output array will contain objects from 1st input array with id not found in 2nd input array objects.

2) 2nd output array will contain objects from 2nd input array with id not found in 1st input array objects.

3) 3rd output array will contain objects from 2nd input array with id found in 1st input array objects, but with different data field.

To better understand the task: you have 2 arrays of objects. 1st array - old objects, 2nd array - new objects. We define 2 objects are same if "id" is same. You need to find object that was deleted, inserted and updated.

This what I have tried.

```
$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];

//for first array
foreach ($array1 as $id1 => $data1) {
   foreach ($array2 as $id2 => $data2) {
       if ($id1 == $id2) {
          $new_array1[$id1] = $data1; 
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: We will NOT do your homework! Show some effort and show where you got stuck, then youll get help...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php - array_filter

Comment: Okay Nidhoegger, its just that i'm stuck

Comment: Show some code possible inputs and expected outputs